# Glitch when interactively dismiss a modal view controller

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, interactive

I am using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` to interactively dismiss a modally presented view controller. Nothing too fancy. But I noticed there is occasionally a small glitch just when the interaction starts. It becomes more noticeable if it is animated with `.curveEaseOut` option. Same thing happens with some online tutorial I am following (https://www.thorntech.com/2016/02/ios-tutorial-close-modal-dragging/). You can see the glitch in the gif when I drag it down for the first time. Any suggestions?

[image]

### MyDismissAnimator

```
class SlideInDismissAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    // ...

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to), 
        let presentedVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else {return}

        let presentedFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: presentedVC)
        var dismissedFrame = presentedFrame
        dismissedFrame.origin.y = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.height

        transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, belowSubview: presentedVC.view)
        }
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            presentedVC.view.frame = dismissedFrame
        }) { _ in
            if transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled {
                toVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
    }
}
```

### MyInteractor

```
class SwipeInteractionController: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {

    var interactionInProgress = false
    private var shouldCompleteTransition = false
    private weak var viewController: UIViewController!

    init(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        super.init()
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
        viewController.view?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func handleGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizer.view!.superview!)
        var progress = (translation.y / viewController.view.bounds.height)
        progress = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(progress), 0.0), 1.0))

        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            interactionInProgress = true
            viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        case .changed:
            shouldCompleteTransition = progress > 0.3
            update(progress)

        case .cancelled:
            interactionInProgress = false
            cancel()

        case .ended:
            interactionInProgress = false
            if shouldCompleteTransition {
                finish()
            } else {
                cancel()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you calling `animateTransition` function from a background thread? Can you make sure it gets called from main thread?

Comment: @Honey, `animateTransition` is inside the dismiss animator, and is automatically called by UIKit. So I guess that isn't the problem? Let me know how you think it should be done

Comment: hah. I thought it was a function you wrote yourself. My bad. No that isn't a problem. Just making sure: You have't enabled slow animations on your Xcode have? To avoid that Simulator >> Debug >> Slow animations...

Comment: No, I can't even find that option in Xcode now

Comment: its on the simulator app, not xcode...

Comment: I'm having the same issue, for me it seems to be that the dismissal starts animating without interaction immediately and then subsequent calls to the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.update(_:) cause the animation to stop and reset to the correct time in the animation. If I stop calling update(_:) the animation still completes on its own, even through it shouldn't because it should wait for a call to finish() or cancel(). I'm not sure what is causing this to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slowly panning in UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition results in glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224242/slowly-panning-in-uipercentdriveninteractivetransition-results-in-glitch)

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug with the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, but I was able to resolve this:

The bug occurs when the progress is not updated as soon as possible after dismiss() is called. This happens because the pan gesture recognizer's .changed state is only triggered as you're dragging. So if you're dragging slowly, between the time .begin is called and the first .changed is called, the dismiss transition will start to animate.

You can see this in the simulator by very slowly dragging on the view, pixel by pixel, until .begin is called. As long as .changed doesn't  get called again, the transition will actually complete itself and you'll see the view animate all the way down and transition complete.

However, simply calling update(progress) after .dismiss() doesn't work either, I believe because the dismiss animation hasn't begun yet. (until the next runloop or something)

My "hack" solution was to dispatch async with a very tiny amount of time, effectively setting the progress and halting the animation before it begins.

```
case .began:
    interactionInProgress = true
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
        self.update(progress)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For interative dissmiss, the animation delay must be greater than 0 on iOS 11.

ref: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/blob/master/Pod/Classes/SideMenuTransition.swift#L510

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom dismissal transition animator you should not add view of toViewController as subview to container view of transitionContext. It's already in hierarchy. That bug took place im my same case, but i used both dismissal and appear custom animations. I think for only custom dismissal animation this takes place, too.
Delete this line:

```
transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, belowSubview: presentedVC.view)
```

All you should do this case - change frame of fromViewController in animation block to what you want.

Comment: Hi @Sergey. The problem gets worse with glitch happening every time the interaction started. Plus, the background is completely black during transition, then suddenly comes back when it completes...

Comment: @JGuo, ok, i wa wrong thinking that it's already in hierarchy. What's happening when you disable interactive animator? If the glitch will not appear - it's not the interactive animator's problem.  
One more idea: it could be problem with your presented VC (layout/frameSize, if it's dynamically changes by some constraints in viewWillAppear), because if you interactive animator adjusted special way it could call "cancelled" status of gesture recognizer. This will call viewWillAppear of your dismissing VC and it could jump bec frame in VWA differ from frame if dismissal animation code. Just idea

Comment: Everything works perfectly if I just dismiss it without interaction. No, it's just a plain `UIViewController` with nothing but `backgroundColor = .white`

Comment: @JGuo attach code of interactive transition controller, please

Comment: added, pretty standard implementation, nothing fancy

Comment: @JGuo try add *UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent* option to animation. I don't see actual problem in these files, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by "embracing" the glitch. 
The problem is the old view is moved down a bit before the interactor kicks in. Then the control is given to the interactor that resets the position to the beginning of the animation moving it back.
If the interactor begins the animation at the same position where the old view is when it is given control, then the glitch is almost un-noticeable.

To do this I removed the easing curve parameter from UIView.animate, and applied my own easing function to the progress before calling update(progress).

My custom easing function has an offset parameter that compensate the movement happening before the interactor takes control.

You have to find the correct amount for the offset parameter depending on the transition duration that you apply. For a transition duration of 0.3 the sweet spot is an offset of 0.05.

You can download a working example here: https://github.com/francosolerio/InteractiveModal

**Easing functions**

```
struct Curves {
    static func quadraticEaseIn<T: FloatingPoint>(t: T) -> T {
        return t * t
    }

    static func quadraticEaseOut<T: FloatingPoint>(t: T) -> T {
        return 1 - quadraticEaseIn(t: 1 - t)
    }

    static func QuadraticEaseInOut<T: FloatingPoint>(t: T) -> T {
        if t < 1/2 {
            return quadraticEaseIn(t: t * 2) / 2
        } else {
            return 1 - quadraticEaseIn(t: (1 - t) * 2) / 2
        }
    }

    static func quadraticEaseOut<T: FloatingPoint>(t: T, offset: T) -> T {
        return quadraticEaseOut(t: t + offset)
    }    
}
```

**Animator**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
                fromVC.view.frame = finalFrame
            },
            completion: { _ in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            }
        )
```

**Interactor**

```
var progress = Curves.quadraticEaseOut(t: translation.y / viewController.view.bounds.height, offset: 0.05)
        progress = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(progress), 0.0), 1.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue where the dismiss animation starts "on its own" (disregarding any interaction) before being controlled by the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.
Then I thought the dismiss animation that's taking place in those initial milliseconds is actually your own custom animation provided by your implementation of :

```
animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

So what you can do is **increase the duration** of your custom animation, something like 10 seconds, and the initial jittering no longer happens.
In order for the "post interaction" animation to occur at a regular speed (ie. when you let go of your view controller), you increase the completion speed or your UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition instance with the following line:

```
percentDrivenTransition.completionSpeed = 10.0
```

Without it, the remainder of your animation would take several seconds, and that's not what we want here.

Hope that helps.